# How to go through through object's instance properties?

Tags: javascript, performance

In the following statement, `Object#hasOwnProperty()` is used to check if the current property is a property of an instance of an object and not from the prototype chain. This means nevermind this condition, the `for` loop will go through the entire list of properties contained in the prototype chain.

```js
for (key in obj) 
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    iterator.call(context, obj[key], key);
  }
}
```

I would like to know if there is a way to get rid of this behavior and **only** go through the list of properties of the instance of an object?

---

As mentioned through the tags, I'm mainly asking the question for performance interests. I'm making this precision because one response proposes to use `Object#getOwnPropertyNames()` but all benchmarks I saw seem to prove that `for…in` with `hasOwnProperty` versus `getOwnPropertyNames` is pretty defavorable for `getOwnPropertyNames`. For example: [jsperf.com/for-in-vs-object-getownpropertynames](http://jsperf.com/for-in-vs-object-getownpropertynames) or [jsperf.com/for-in-vs-getownpropertynames-and-foreach/5](http://jsperf.com/for-in-vs-getownpropertynames-and-foreach/5)

Answer (score 0):

[`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) Returns an array of all properties (enumerable or not) found directly upon a given object.

So you can replace that `for` loop with something like this:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames( obj ).forEach( function( key ){
    iterator.call(context, obj[key], key);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fL2gH/

Comment: Thanks! The thing is that all benchmarks I saw seem to prove that `for…in` with `hasOwnProperty` versus `getOwnPropertyNames` is pretty defavorable for `getOwnPropertyNames`. For example: http://jsperf.com/for-in-vs-object-getownpropertynames or http://jsperf.com/for-in-vs-getownpropertynames-and-foreach/5